# How to test store license in my Win32 app converted to UWP using Desktop Bridge (Project Centennial)?

Tags: winapi, uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I have converted my Win32 app written with C/C++/MFC into a UWP app using [Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop). The app will be published in the store under `trial license`. I [found this code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/implement-a-trial-version-of-your-app) that illustrates how to check for trial license, its expiration, etc using [StoreAppLicense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.services.store.storeapplicense.aspx) class.

My issue is how to test it?

My app is built in the older version of VS that did not have a concept of the Windows Store.

Answer (score 2):

> My issue is how to test it

There are two namespaces related to IAP function: **`Windows.Services.Store`** and **`Windows.ApplicationModel.Store`**.

If use the **`Windows.ApplicationModel.Store`** namespace, these apps can use the [CurrentAppSimulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh779766) class to simulate license info during testing. See [In-app purchases and trials using the Windows.ApplicationModel.Store namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials-using-the-windows-applicationmodel-store-namespace)

While the **`Windows.Services.Store`** namespace doesn't have a class to do so.

Please see the [testing guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#testing)

The `Windows.Services.Store` namespace does not provide a class that you can use to simulate license info during testing. **Instead, you must publish an app to the Store and download that app to your development device to use its license for testing**. This is a different experience from apps that use the Windows.ApplicationModel.Store namespace, as these apps can use the CurrentAppSimulator class to simulate license info during testing

---

**(Update 10/21/2016)**

> I'm not clear about your development device sentence though. The app is developed on a Windows 8.1 device and is uploaded via a Chrome browser

That sentence is quoted from [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#testing)

It means we need to convert the Win32 application to Converted UWP app and upload to the Store first, even though we have not implemented the IAP function.

> Is there a way to manually associate an app with a Windows desktop?

Sure, please see [Create your app by reserving a name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/create-your-app-by-reserving-a-name)

Here is a screenshot of App identity of a uwp app on the [Windows Dev Center](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/dashboard)

[image]

**Note, please fill this form if you need to upload a Converted UWP app: [LINK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge)**

This request needs several business days to get response.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am using a new `Windows.Services.Store` namespace. That's what MS docs recommended for a converted Win32 app. I'm not clear about your development device sentence though. The app is developed on a Windows 8.1 device and is uploaded via a Chrome browser. There's nothing afaik that ties that app to any device. Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Follow-up: like I said above the app is developed as a Win32 app in the version of the `Visual Studio` that has no notion of the `Windows Store`. Is there a way to manually associate an app with a Windows desktop?

Comment: @c00000fd please see my updated answer: **(Update 10/21/2016)**

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if I didn't mention this. I already have this converted Win32 app published in the Windows Store (via a private link) -- I am an "early adopter." (I think that's what's it's called.) And true, I had to add app identity to the `AppxManifest.xml` file to be able to publish. So how do I proceed with the testing after that? I'm mostly concerned with the app's trial period and payment options.

Comment: Okay, if you have already published this app, you need to move to the [next step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#testing): *2.If you want to offer add-ons for your app, define the add-ons for your app in the Windows Dev Center dashboard.*, then you can perform tasks such as getting the add-ons available for the current app, purchasing an app or add-on, or getting license info for your app. The [tesing guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#testing) has the clear steps

Comment: No, at this point I don't need any add-ons. I want to let users download my app on a trial basis for 7 days. I set it up in the store, but the question is how do I test the payment process for the trial version? I set up the code, but it brings me to the Store. Do I need to make an actual purchase to test it?

Comment: that's a big store oversight, having to actually BUY your own license to test the darn thing <g> - but I believe the way round it is to offer yourself a promo code (=free license) and test with that

Comment: Does this all mean that when you publish your app to Store and choose 7 DAY TRIAL,  you actually need to make changes to your code to limit the usage of trial to 7 days?   My understanding was that Store itself stops the App after 7 days and gives a warning or something.